# auto complete text view doesnt work

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

why it doesn't display any auto corrections my array got strings

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Sentence");
alert.setMessage("type only words you taught him!!!");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
//final EditText input = new EditText(this);
//alert.setView(input);
// Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
final AutoCompleteTextView textView = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
// Get the string array
//String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
// Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mywords);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
alert.setView(textView);
alert.setPositiveButton("Order", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value =textView.getText().toString();

  String[] inputarray;
  value=value.trim();
  inputarray=value.split(" ");
     playnum=new int[inputarray.length];
      for(int j=0;j<inputarray.length;j++)
      {
          legit=0;
          for(int i=0;i<mywords.length;i++)
          {
          if(info.choosetext[Integer.parseInt(mywords[i])].equalsIgnoreCase(inputarray[j])){
              playnum[j]=Integer.parseInt(mywords[i]);
            legit++;
          }
          }
          if(legit==0)
              break;

      }





      if(legit!=0){     
          playone=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), getResources().getIdentifier("word" + Integer.toString(playnum[0]), "raw", getPackageName()));
         gottext=true;
      }
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

i want it to display array suggestions and on click input it into the text view and now i am talking just cause i got too much code and can't post

someone got to know how to do this without xml

Comment: i beg for help i am new at this

Answer (score 0):

At least one thing you should do is to declare the autocomplete text view in xml and get a reference to it by calling `AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` instead of `final AutoCompleteTextView textView = new AutoCompleteTextView (this)`

Here is a good tutorial on autocomplete text views: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: my layout not in xml its a java layout

Answer (score 0):

try this,
**textview.setThreshold(1);**
after textview.setAdapter()

Comment: tried d it still nothing the text warting works but no suggestions

Comment: i starting to think its impossible inside alert althought edittext autocorrect works

Comment: noticed that if i left click the global dictionary is still there(left click ontext and i get suggestion from global dictionary)